# Find broker id used in the Kafka cluster

Tags: apache-kafka

I want to know the list of taken broker ids in a kafka cluster. For example, in a cluster with 10 nodes if I create a topic with 10 partitions(or more) I can see from the output of a describe topic command, the brokers to which it has been assigned.

```
./bin/kafka-topics --describe --zookeeper <zkconnect>:2181 --topic rbtest3
```

Can I collect this information without creating a topic?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get list of used broker ids using zookeeper cli.

```
zookeeper-3.4.8$ ./bin/zkCli.sh -server zookeeper-1:2181 ls /brokers/ids | tail -1
[0]
```

Comment: Can I achieve this same functionality using kafka binaries?

Comment: You can try with zookeeper-shell.sh script included with Kafka distribution, but I couldn't make it work in non-interactive mode.

Comment: @LucianoAfranllie @jmathews Hi! I just noticed these comments. I posted this as an answer below, which worked for me: `linux$ ./zookeeper-shell.sh zookeeper-IPaddress:2181 <<< "ls`

Comment: To get node details, try "./bin/zkCli.sh -server zookeeper-1:2181 get /brokers/ids/[brokerid from previous command]"

Answer (score 7):

You also can use the `zookeeper-shell.sh` script that ships with the **Kafka** distribution, like this:

`linux$ ./zookeeper-shell.sh zookeeper-IPaddress:2181 <<< "ls /brokers/ids"`

Just add the IP address of any of your Zookeeper servers (and/or change the port if necessary, for example when running multiple Zookeeper instances on the same server).

This alternative can be useful when, for example, you find yourself inside a container (Docker, LXC, etc.) that is exclusively running a Kafka client; but Zookeeper itself is somewhere else (say, in a different container).

I hope it helps. =:)

Answer (score 3):

```
#kafka broker id
cat $KAFKA_HOME/logs/meta.properties
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know what is the broker ID of a specific broker - the easiest way is to look at its controller.log, I found:

```
cat /var/log/kafka/controller.log
[2021-02-18 13:20:22,639] INFO [ControllerEventThread controllerId=1003] Starting (kafka.controller.ControllerEventManager$ControllerEventThread)
[2021-02-18 13:20:22,646] DEBUG [Controller id=1003] Broker 1002 has been elected as the controller, so stopping the election process. (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
```

controllerId=1003 ---> this is your brokerID (1003)

[substitute your path to the kafka logs, of course ...]

Answer (score 1):

you can use kafka-manager, an open-source tool powered by yahoo.

Answer (score 1):

You can run the following command:

```js
bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --topic=<your topic> --broker-list=<your broker list>  --time=-2
```

This will list all of the brokers with their id and the beginning offset.

Comment: I wanted the list of brokers to be the output of the command. The command above takes broker list and topic as arguments. What I want is to know all the brokers currently available in the cluster as a list of broker ids.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Zookeeper CLI

`sh /bin/zkCli.sh -server zookeeper-1:2181 ls /brokers/ids`

Then to get details of the broker, you can use the "get" with the ids that was the output generated from the previous command

`sh /bin/zkCli.sh -server zookeeper-1:2181 get /brokers/ids/<broker-id>`